# Rails webrick force-exits: uninitialized constant WebConsole::Railtie::Middleware (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, webrick

So I'm a newbie in ruby trying to start up webrick for the first time. I just recently fixed the segmentation fault error with the mysql2, and got hit with this new exit issue. Here's the command line readout:

> G:\Ruby Development\simple_cms>
>
> G:\Ruby Development\simple_cms>rails server
>
> => Booting WEBrick
>
> => Rails 4.2.1 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
>
> => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
>
> => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
>
> Exiting
>
> C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.1.2/lib/web_console/railtie.rb:21:in`block in ': uninitialized constant WebConsole::Railtie::Middleware (NameError)
>
> from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
>
> from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
>
> from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
>
> from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
>
> from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
>
> from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:429:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
>
> from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
>
> from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
>
> from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
>
> from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
>
> from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
>
> from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:203:in `tsort_each'
>
> from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
>
> from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
>
> from G:/Ruby Development/simple_cms/config/environment.rb:5:in `'
>
> from G:/Ruby Development/simple_cms/config.ru:3:in `require'
>
> from G:/Ruby Development/simple_cms/config.ru:3:in `block in '
>
> from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
>
> from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
>
> from G:/Ruby Development/simple_cms/config.ru:in `new'
>
> from G:/Ruby Development/simple_cms/config.ru:in `'
>
> from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
>
> from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
>
> from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
>
> from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/server.rb:299:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
>
> from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/server.rb:208:in `app'
>
> from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:61:in `app'
>
> from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/server.rb:336:in `wrapped_app'
>
> from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:139:in `log_to_stdout'
>
> from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:78:in `start'
>
> from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
>
> from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
>
> from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
>
> from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
>
> from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `'
>
> from bin/rails:4:in `require'
>
> from bin/rails:4:in `'

From what I understand so far I am loading the server up at least. so this isn't a part of the segmentation fault, right?

My gemfile includes web-console 2.1.2. Also, I've ran 'bundle install' just in case. Any insight into this error? Let me know if any more information is needed.

Rails Version -4.2.1
Ruby Version - 2.2.1p85

Comment: does anyone know if I should try an earlier version of ruby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two rails executables.  Your PATH is pointing you to the wrong one. Type 'which rails': you should get "~/bin/rails", a stub that railties puts in your home directory.  If you get something else, rename the rails executable there and try again.

Comment: Worked! thank you. Rails was installed on one drive and trying to point to another