# Rails webrick force-exits: uninitialized constant WebConsole::Railtie::Middleware

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, webrick

just trying to run `WEBrick` on windows using `rails s` but getting following error

```
Rails webrick force-exits: uninitialized constant WebConsole::Railtie::Middleware (NameError)
```

I looked into following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29325381/rails-webrick-force-exits-uninitialized-constant-webconsolerailtiemiddlewar) but it didn't helped me at all, I'm unable to run `which` command on windows, also I've only one ruby installation.

```
ruby 2.2.2p95
rails 4.2.0
```

Comment: Try running `bin/rails s` or `bundle exec rails s` instead. This will run the app in the context of the current `Gemfile`, instead of from your PATH. If that doesn't work, try removing (or commenting out) `gem 'webconsole'` in your Gemfile and run `bundle install`

Comment: did all, but got the same results :(

Comment: Can you post the output of `rake middleware` into your question? I think I might debug your middleware problem.